# How to use DiffUtil with multiple View types

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils

I have implemented a recyclerview with multiple view types , and i want to add DiffUtil . I managed to do so for one type but when i try to support multiple view types i can't

So my question is : does  DiffUtil supports multiple view types and is there a good tutorial for java implementation

**My Adapter**

```
public class PostsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {


    private final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_AD = 1;
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_CATEGORIES = 2;
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_NULL = 99;

    private Context context;
    private List<Object> postList;

    public PostsAdapter() {
    }

    /*public PostsAdapter() {
        super(Post.DIFF_CALLBACK);
    }*/

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();

        switch (viewType){
            case VIEW_TYPE_ITEM:
                View viewItem = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_post,
                        parent, false);
                return new ItemViewHolder(viewItem);

            case VIEW_TYPE_AD:
                View unifiedNativeLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_ads,
                        parent, false);
                return new AdsViewHolder(unifiedNativeLayoutView);

            case VIEW_TYPE_CATEGORIES:
                View viewCategories = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_categories,
                        parent, false);
                return new HorizontalItemViewHolder(viewCategories);
            default:
                View viewLoading = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_loading,
                        parent, false);
                return new LoadingViewHolder(viewLoading);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);

        switch (viewType){
            case VIEW_TYPE_ITEM:
                populateItemRows((ItemViewHolder) holder, position);
                break;
            case VIEW_TYPE_AD:
                populateNativeAdModule((AdsViewHolder) holder, position);
                break;
            case VIEW_TYPE_CATEGORIES:
                populateHorizontalItems((HorizontalItemViewHolder) holder, position);

            default:
                showLoadingView();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Object recyclerViewItem = postList.get(position);

        if(recyclerViewItem instanceof UnifiedNativeAd){
            return  VIEW_TYPE_AD;
        }else if(postList.get(position) == null){
            return VIEW_TYPE_NULL;
            // Empty Ad view
        }else{
            return VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }



    private static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private CardView cardView1;

        ItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cardView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_post);


        }

        void setName(String text1) {
            TextView name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            name.setText(text1);
        }

    }



    private static class HorizontalItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private RecyclerView RV;

        HorizontalItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            // Samedi
            RV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_categories);
        }


    }

    private static class AdsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TemplateView template ;

        AdsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            template = itemView.findViewById(R.id.adview_feed);

        }
    }

    private static class LoadingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        LoadingViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        }
    }


    private void showLoadingView() {
        //ProgressBar would be displayed

    }

    private void populateItemRows(final ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {

       // *****  Codes /// 
    }

    private void populateHorizontalItems(final HorizontalItemViewHolder holder, final int position){

        // *****  Codes /// 

    }

    private void populateNativeAdModule(AdsViewHolder nativeAdHolder,
                                        final int position ){

         // *****  ADS Codes /// 

    }

}
    }
```

Comment: `DiffUtil` is related to model-style data, not views. I suggest that you edit your question and post the entire `PostAdapter` implementation.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this case? If yes please share it

Comment: You can refer to this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63019699/using-recyclerview-with-diffutil-for-multiple-data-types

Answer (score 1):

I saw many people view this, post, but nobody responded that's why I decided to share my solution:

//Methods Submitlist + getItemViewType are very important to create. Therefore,

RecyclerView.ViewHolde extends from "**import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView**" it's a native class from Java

//The interface is important too, to bind with diferent types of view

```
class MensajeAdapter(val idSender:String?): ListAdapter<MessageOne, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(DiffCallback) {

// DiffCallback
companion object{
    private lateinit var txtMessageSender       : TextView
    private lateinit var txtFechaSender         : TextView
    private lateinit var imgStateMessage        : ImageView
             private var itemNew                : String = ""
             private var listMessages           = mutableListOf<MessageOne>()


    private val DiffCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<MessageOne>()
    {
        //verifica si el objeto (o la fila de la base de datos, en tu caso) es el mismo que verifica el ID
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: MessageOne, newItem: MessageOne): Boolean {
            return oldItem.dateSort == newItem.dateSort
        }
        //verifica si todas las propiedades, no solo el ID, son iguales.
        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: MessageOne, newItem: MessageOne): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }

    }

}

override fun submitList(list: MutableList<MessageOne>?) {
    if (list != null) {
        listMessages = list
    }
    super.submitList(list)
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {

    return when(listMessages[position].idUsuario){
            idSender -> TypeCommunication.SENDER.typeCommunication
            else -> TypeCommunication.RECEIVER.typeCommunication
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

   return when(viewType)
   {
       TypeCommunication.SENDER.typeCommunication ->{
           println("Es Sender")
           ViewHolderRight(parent.inflate(R.layout.item_mensaje_user))
       }
       else -> {
           println("Es Received")
           println("LA combinacion: itemNew:$itemNew  --- $idSender")
           ViewHolderLeft(parent.inflate(R.layout.item_mensaje_remoto))
       }
   }
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    (holder as ChatViewHolder).bindView(getItem(position), idSender)
}

interface ChatViewHolder {
    fun bindView(item: MessageOne, idSender: String?)
}


class ViewHolderRight(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView),ChatViewHolder {

    private val binding = ItemMensajeUserBinding.bind(itemView)

    override fun bindView(item: MessageOne, idSender: String?) {
        binding.apply {
            txtFechaSender = lblFechaMensaje
            txtMessageSender = lblTextUser
            imgStateMessage = imgVistoMensajeria
        }

        itemView.apply{
            //Ocultar Notificaciones Y Mensajes Nuevos
             txtFechaSender.text = item.horaRegi
             txtMessageSender.text = item.mensaje
             imgStateMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_done)

        }
    }


}

class ViewHolderLeft(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView),ChatViewHolder {

    private val binding = ItemMensajeRemotoBinding.bind(itemView)

    override fun bindView(item: MessageOne, idSender: String?) {
        binding.apply {
            txtFechaSender = lblMfechaRemoto
            txtMessageSender = lblTextMsjRemoto
            imgStateMessage = imgVistoMensajeriaRemoto
        }

        itemView.apply{
            //Ocultar Notificaciones Y Mensajes Nuevos
            txtFechaSender.text = item.horaRegi
            txtMessageSender.text = item.mensaje
            imgStateMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_done)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

DiffUtil does not interst your views, only models come from adapter. It seems you want make diff on `postList` that consists different kind of types (item, ad etc.)

You can use `DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Object>` as you did in `getItemViewType` for `Object` type.

Comment: Can you explain me how , i am a beginner